# Can I implement an autonomous `self` member type in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

C++ [lacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143699/560648) the equivalent of [PHP's `self` keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), which evaluates to the type of the enclosing class.

It's easy enough to fake it on a per-class basis:

```
struct Foo
{
   typedef Foo self;
};
```

but I had to write `Foo` again. Maybe I'll get this wrong one day and cause a silent bug.

Can I use some combination of `decltype` and friends to make this work "autonomously"? [I tried the following already](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/583a8651b5f8a46c) but `this` is not valid in that place:

```
struct Foo
{
   typedef decltype(*this) self;
};

// main.cpp:3:22: error: invalid use of 'this' at top level
//     typedef decltype(*this) self;
```

<sup>(I'm not going to worry about the equivalent of `static`, which does the same but with late binding.)</sup>

Comment: `this_t` would be probably more aligned with regular C++ naming.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: or this_type

Comment: Will you accept C++14 answers too? It could work there.

Comment: Can you give an example where this would be necessary? What's wrong with `this`?

Comment: @rwols: for **type information** at the scope of the class definition, not just the nonstatic implementation? I.e. it'd be nice to be able to write ` public:  treenode_type<ThisT> clone() const;` etc. It'd saves you sometimes much work when renaming the classes (and if you cannot 'refactor' it automatically).

Comment: Even if you did manage to create the `typedef` the way you want it, you'd still have to repeat the class name for constructors. There's no alternative to that.

Comment: @Praetorian, I can't remember if it was a proposal or not, but someone suggested `auto()` and `~auto()` for ctors/dtors. Interesting to say the least. If used for that purpose, perhaps `typedef auto self;`, but that seems a bit sketchy to me.

Comment: @Praetorian: But you see a solid, guaranteed compiler error if you get _those_ wrong.

Comment: @rwols: `this` is an expression, not a type, and it does not exist inside `static` member functions.

Comment: Oh my.. dtors/ctors like `auto() ~auto()` seem sooo great.. edit: at first glance anyways.

Comment: Honestly, if I was going to suggest syntax to make this possible, it would probably be `decltype(class)`, maybe with a `decltype(struct)` equivalent. That's much clearer than just `auto` in a specific context and I don't see any problems with it fitting into the language based on `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: +1 for that. Usage like `decltype(class)const&` can start looking odd, but still it would be clear and succint solution.

Comment: Since you want to avoid errors, you may set up an dummy member function with static_assert, like `void _check() { static_assert(std::is_same<self&, decltype(*this)>::value, "Correct your self type"); }` Doesn't work with class templates, though...

Comment: @chris: Yeah I like it

Comment: @chris `class` seems restrictive: `decltype(typename)` is the type of the enclosing type?  I guess arrays would be an issue, as you don't know how big they are until they are done.  But `decltype(typename)` in the body of an `enum` might be useful.  I guess `class` would imply that if you used it in a lambda inside the `class` it would still return the enclosing `class`?  Does it work in bodies which are not inline in the `class` definition?

Comment: @Yakk, Interesting points. Either way works for me. I would expect that it would give the type of the lambda functor, yes, and that it would work in more than just the class definition if that doesn't cause unforseen problems. Another handy use might be in definitions: `void decltype(typename)::foo() {}`

Comment: Code is read far more often than it's written, and classes are read FAR more often than they're renamed. If you *insist* upon having a `self` or `this_t` typedef (and there's absolutely no situation in which you need it), then you should just write it out. Everything suggested here creates a LOT more confusion than clarity. If you want to rename a class, why are you not using find&replace? You don't have to use replace all, just use find next, replace, find next, replace, etc.

Comment: @MilesRout: What fun is that?!

Comment: _and cause a silent bug_ Surely you will cause (most likely) a noisy bug.

Comment: @PaulSanders: If you're lucky! What you need to be worried about are the silent ones :) Particularly these days when everyone is obsessing over `auto` and/or duck typing (or, at least, simulating it) so there's no longer a point-of-failure diagnostic when you've used the wrong type... you just sort of have to hope that at some point down the line some signatures won't match any more and you finally discover that you made a mistake last year.

Comment: Instead of decltype(typename) - why not just decltype()?

Comment: @Pete [It doesn't work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d94518f4fa0a7a43), is the main flaw. What is `decltype()`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit looking back over the comments, decltype(class) or decltype(typename) were suggested as possible future syntax.   Seems to me that using an empty expression to decltype would be just as clear as decltype(typename) to identify the type of the enclosing scope.  And no it is not getting through the compiler today.  Wonder if it could be worth making a syntax proposal.

Comment: @MilesRout, your "self-invalidatingly" hard, dogmatic stance (with those CAPS and _italics_ and "absolutes") misses (among other things) one crucial point entirely (despite explicitly written in the question), which is: reading a class (no matter how many times more than writing) can't put bugs in it.

Comment: @Pete Oh I see. Yes that'd be nice actually

Comment: There has been a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0874r0.html) to have a syntax for this (and other similar cases), but it’s been sidelined while work on more general reflection work is ongoing.

Comment: _"Different names have been discussed, including decltype(class), typename(typename) namespace(namespace)"_ Ugh!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here's how you can do it without repeating the type of Foo:

```
template <typename...Ts>
class Self;

template <typename X, typename...Ts>
class Self<X,Ts...> : public Ts...
{
protected:
    typedef X self;
};

#define WITH_SELF(X) X : public Self<X>
#define WITH_SELF_DERIVED(X,...) X : public Self<X,__VA_ARGS__>

class WITH_SELF(Foo)
{
    void test()
    {
        self foo;
    }
};
```

If you want to derive from `Foo` then you should use the macro `WITH_SELF_DERIVED` in the following way:

```
class WITH_SELF_DERIVED(Bar,Foo)
{
    /* ... */
};
```

You can even do multiple inheritance with as many base classes as you want (thanks to variadic templates and variadic macros):

```
class WITH_SELF(Foo2)
{
    /* ... */
};

class WITH_SELF_DERIVED(Bar2,Foo,Foo2)
{
    /* ... */
};
```

I have verified this to work on gcc 4.8 and clang 3.4.

Comment: I guess the answer is "no, but Ralph can!" ;)

Comment: How is this in any way superior to simply putting the typedef in there? And god, why would you even need the typedef? Why?

Comment: @MilesRout This is a question about the question, not the answer. In many cases in software development (and especially maintenance) it is helpful to avoid redundancies in the code, so that changing something in one place does not require you to change code in another place. That's the whole point of `auto` and `decltype` or in this case of `self`.

Comment: `template<typename T>class Self{protected: typedef T self;}; class WITH_SELF(Foo) : public Bar, private Baz {};` would have been simpler and would allow more precise control over inheritance - any reasons against?

Comment: @mmmmmmmm, if you haven't learned to deeply appreciate the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle, chances are you haven't coded quite enough/seriously yet. This "clutter" (far from it, actually) is quite an elegant fix in the context of talking about an inelegant language feature (or misfeature, even deficiency by some strict measures).

Comment: How to do private or protected inheritance with this solution?!?!

Comment: Have you another magical Ralph trick for template classes ? :-D

Answer (score 39):

A possible workaround (as you still have to write the type once):

```
template<typename T>
struct Self
{
protected:
    typedef T self;
};

struct Foo : public Self<Foo>
{
    void test()
    {
        self obj;
    }
};
```

For a more safer version we could assure that `T` actually derives from `Self<T>`:

```
Self()
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Self<T>, T>::value, "Wrong type passed to Self");
}
```

Notice that a `static_assert` inside a member function is probably the only way to check, as types passed to`std::is_base_of` have to be complete.

Comment: No need for `typename` in the typedef. And since this doesn’t reduce the number of redundancies I don’t think it’s a viable alternative.

Comment: It has exactly the same problem of repeating `Foo` name.

Comment: It _is_ marginally better than the original approach, though, since the repetition is very close together. Not a solution to the question, but +1 for a worthy attempt at a best-case workaround.

Comment: I used that solution a couple of times, and it has one BAD thing: when later deriving from `Foo`, you have to either: (1) propagate the T upwards to the leaf-descendant, or (2) remember to inherit from SelfT many times, or (3) accept that all children thing to be the Base.. usable, but unpretty.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Since I'm trying to replicate `self` rather than `static`, that's no problem.

Comment: Oh, got a typo: `children thing`->`children think`. Sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean now. For me, all (1-2-3) I wrote are quite bad. (1) prevents you from creating nontemplate descendant that uses this feature, (2) sometimes prevents you from inspecting the actual type, and (3) paritally turns off the feature when using inheritance.. if you are aware of it and OK - cool! Also, I don't understand what you mean by `replicating the <static>` since in C++ `static` is keyword of much different meaning (actually, at least two contextual meanings). Is it in PHP something like `this/self`?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Let me clarify: "since I'm trying to replicate PHP's `self` rather than PHP's `static`, that's no problem". In PHP, `static` is like `self` but with late-binding (which solves the problems you just listed). That is, I only need to care about the "current" type and do not need to worry about inheritance. (In the real world we probably do, but I figured I'd get this base case out of the way first before thinking about that.)

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I didn't know there's `static` in PHP. What you say is clear. However, you might misunderstood what I said. If you care about early-bound 'current type' that what I've said holds true. Having `Foo::Self<Foo>` makes `Foo::self` to be `Foo`. But having then inheritance `Bar : public Foo` preserves that and `Bar::self` is still `Foo`, and using `self` in child class as early-bound type information starts to be problematic since you landed at point (3). You could `Bar : public Foo, public Self<Bar>` and land at (2), or `Bar : Foo<Bar>` ~(1). Sorry about nitpicking..

Comment: Another annoyance is that if `Foo<X>` is a `template`, accessing `self` requires doing `typename Self<Foo<X>>::self` which really doesn't help.  :)

Comment: And apart from **all** of that, it's still very confusing for anyone reading the code. What on earth is self, and what does it mean? It's a LOT easier to remember to change all instances of the class name in its definition (a single find&replace operation) than to expect everyone that ever inherits from the class to remember to add `self_<bar>` to their definitions.

Answer (score 32):

I have no positive evidence but I *think* it’s impossible. The following fails – for the same reason as your attempt – and I think that’s the furthest we can get:

```
struct Foo {
    auto self_() -> decltype(*this) { return *this; }

    using self = decltype(self_());
};
```

Essentially, what this demonstrates is that the scope at which we want to declare our typedef simply has *no* access (be it direct or indirect) to `this`, and there’s no other (compiler independent) way of getting to the class’ type or name.

Comment: Will this be possibly with C++1y's return type deduction?

Comment: @dyp: Not in that form since self_() needs to be called on an object

Comment: @dyp For the purpose of my answer that won’t change anything. The error here isn’t in the trailing return type, it’s in the invocation.

Comment: will `using self = decltype(self_())` compile without instance or Foo:: ? I somewhat doubt.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: The innards of `decltype` is an unevaluated context, so invoking the member function isn't the problem (that won't be attempted)

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer, but by **declaring** `self_` as `static auto self_() -> decltype(*this);`, it works. Then you should however use std::remove_reference in `using self`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I of course understand that this is unevaluated and just inspected. The problem I meant is: will the compiler at all recognize the identifier `self_` as the member of 'current class' without any scope prefix, be it `variable.` or `namespace::`? If it will pick it (I **very** doubt, but my knowledge of C++ is quite old now), it will work. Else, it will fail with unrecognized symbol.

Comment: @TomKnapen Try it with clang, and it'll fail. The fact that it's accepted by GCC is a bug, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @TomKnapen: static + this? really? Please include compiler information. I'm pretty sure it is not valid.

Comment: @hvd whoops, you are right. Didn't try clang before commenting. And quetzalcoatl: I know it looks weird, I didn't expect it to work neither, but it works in GCC 4.8.1

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: Oh, okay. Fair question then.

Comment: FWIW, `struct S { int i; typedef decltype(i) Int; };` works even though `i` is a non-static data member. It works because `decltype` has a special exception where a simple name is not evaluated as an expression. But I cannot think of any way of using this possibility in a way that answers the question.

Comment: Not to mention that it would increase `sizeof(S)` :)

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Why would adding a `typedef` increase the size of `S`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not the `typedef`, but the variable definition it requires to work (via `decltype(i)`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Oh, right, I'm with you - it was only introduced in order to obtain its type. Gotcha. It's been a few months since my brain was melted around this subject ;)

Answer (score 32):

You can use a macro instead of a regular class declaration, that will do that for you.

```
#define CLASS_WITH_SELF(X) class X { typedef X self;
```

And then use like

```
CLASS_WITH_SELF(Foo) 
};
```

`#define END_CLASS };` would probably help readability.

---

You could also take @Paranaix's `Self` and use it (it starts to get really hackish)

```
#define WITH_SELF(X) X : public Self<X>

class WITH_SELF(Foo) {
};
```

Comment: EWWWW END_CLASS. That's totally unnecessary.

Comment: @DeadMG I think some people might like more consistency; after all, the first macro use doesn't end with `{`, so the `}` is "hanging", which text editors would probably dislike, too.

Comment: Nice idea but even though I’m not fundamentally opposed to macros I would only accept its usage here if it mimicked C++ scoping, i.e. if it were usable as `CLASS_WITH_SELF(foo) { … };` – and I think that’s impossible to achieve.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've added a way to do that, too. Not that I like it, just for the sake of completeness

Comment: There are some problems with that approach, though. First one doesn't allow you to make the class inherit easily (unless you use another macro parameter(s)), and second has all the problems of *inheriting from* it that `Self` has.

Comment: To me it looks that inheritance scenarios are the ones where `self` is most useful.

Comment: You can easily inherit.  `WITH_SELF(Foo), public other_parent { ... }` works fine

Comment: @Yakk Not so, if `other_parent` defines a type `self` itself. Then there will be name collisions. Hence, my alternative answer.

Answer (score 23):

What works in both GCC and clang is to create a typedef that refers to `this` by using `this` in the trailing-return-type of a function typedef. Since this is not the declaration of a static member function, the use of `this` is tolerated. You can then use that typedef to define `self`.

```
#define DEFINE_SELF() \
    typedef auto _self_fn() -> decltype(*this); \
    using self = decltype(((_self_fn*)0)())

struct Foo {
    DEFINE_SELF();
};

struct Bar {
    DEFINE_SELF();
};
```

Unfortunately, a strict reading of the standard says that even this is not valid. What clang does is check that `this` is not used in the definition of a static member function. And here, it indeed isn't. GCC doesn't mind if `this` is used in a trailing-return-type regardless of the sort of function, it allows it even for `static` member functions. However, what the standard actually requires is that `this` is not used outside of the definition of a non-static member function (or non-static data member initialiser). Intel gets it right and rejects this.

Given that:

- `this` is only allowed in non-static data member initialisers and non-static member functions ([expr.prim.general]p5),
- non-static data members cannot have their type deduced from the initialiser ([dcl.spec.auto]p5),
- non-static member functions can only be referred to by an unqualified name in the context of a function call ([expr.ref]p4)
- non-static member functions can only be called by unqualified name, even in unevaluated contexts, when `this` can be used ([over.call.func]p3),
- a reference to a non-static member function by qualified name or member access requires a reference to the type being defined

I think I can conclusively say that there is no way at all to implement `self` without including in some way, somewhere, the type name.

**Edit**: There is a flaw in my earlier reasoning. "non-static member functions can only be called by unqualified name, even in unevaluated contexts, when this can be used ([over.call.func]p3)," is incorrect. What it *actually* says is

> If the keyword `this` (9.3.2) is in scope and refers to class `T`, or a derived class of `T`, then the implied object argument is `(*this)`. If the keyword `this` is not in scope or refers to another class, then a contrived object of type `T` becomes the implied object argument. If the argument list is augmented by a contrived object and overload resolution selects one of the non-static member functions of `T`, the call is ill-formed.

Inside a static member function, `this` may not appear, but it still exists.

However, per the comments, inside a static member function, the transformation of `f()` to `(*this).f()` would not be performed, and it that isn't performed, then [expr.call]p1 is violated:

> [...] For a member function call, the postfix expression shall be an implicit (9.3.1, 9.4) or explicit class member access (5.2.5) whose [...]

as there would be no member access. So even that wouldn't work.

Comment: I think [class.mfct.non-static]/3 says that `_self_fn_1()` is "transformed" into `(*this)._self_fn_1()`. Not sure if that makes it illegal, though.

Comment: @dyp It says "is used in a member of class `X` in a context where `this` can be used", so I don't think that transformation is performed.

Comment: But then it is neither an implicit nor explicit class member access..? [expr.call]/1 "For a member function
call, the postfix expression shall be an implicit or explicit class member access [...]"

Comment: (I mean, what happens when you have `auto _self_fn_1() -> decltype(*this); auto _self_fn_1() const -> decltype(*this);`?)

Comment: @dyp [expr.call]/1 is a good point, I'll have to take a closer look. About `const` overloads, though: that isn't a problem. 5.1p3 has specifically been modified to also apply to static member functions, and says the type of `this` is `Foo*`/`Bar*` (without `const`), because there is no `const` in the declaration of `_self_fn_2`.

Comment: @dyp I fear you're right about [expr.call]p1. It may avoid the restrictions on `this`, but that just makes it invalid for another reason.

Answer (score 17):

```
#define SELF_CHECK( SELF ) void self_check() { static_assert( std::is_same< typename std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type, SELF >::value, "self wrong type" ); }
#define SELF(T) typedef T self; SELF_CHECK(T)

struct Foo {
  SELF(Foo); // works, self is defined as `Foo`
};
struct Bar {
  SELF(Foo); // fails
};
```

this does not work on template types, as `self_check` is not called, so the `static_assert` is not evaluated.

We can do some hacks to make it work for `template`s as well, but it has a minor run time cost.

```
#define TESTER_HELPER_TYPE \
template<typename T, std::size_t line> \
struct line_tester_t { \
  line_tester_t() { \
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(T::line_tester), line_tester_t<T,line> >::value, "test failed" ); \
    static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(&T::static_test_zzz), T*(*)() >::value, "test 2 failed" ); \
  } \
}

#define SELF_CHECK( SELF ) void self_check() { static_assert( std::is_same< typename std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type, SELF >::value, "self wrong type" ); }

#define SELF(T) typedef T self; SELF_CHECK(T); static T* static_test_zzz() { return nullptr; }; TESTER_HELPER_TYPE; line_tester_t<T,__LINE__> line_tester
```

an empty `struct` of size 1 byte is created in your class.  If your type is instantiated, `self` is tested against.

Comment: That's not bad either!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit now with `template` class support options.

Comment: I was thinking exactly about this as I was leaving work yesterday. You beat me to it :). I'd suggest declaring self_check() as inline, to avoid linking issues (same symbol Foo::self_check() found in multiple object files).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Uh ... what? I didn't understand a word you said. What's 9.3/2? Pardon my ignorance ...

Comment: @theswine: 9.3/2 is the index of a paragraph in the C++ standard, which guarantees that class member functions _defined in the body of the class definition_ are already, implicitly, `inline`. That means you don't need to write `inline` at all. So if you have been writing `inline` in front of every such class member function definition for your whole career, you can stop now ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, actually I was. Thank you, that will save me some typing in the future :). I'm always amazed by how much I don't know about C++.

Comment: So the `static` `T*` part above does nothing: but the the line check does help.  Need to add in a file name hash to replace the `T*` it... or maybe a literal `constexpr`?

Comment: With a less nice error message, I think `auto self_check() -> enable_if_t< std::is_same<decltype(this), foo*>::value >;` should work as well. [You can also use the same technique and produce a nicer error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f514a8e294255578).

Comment: Not bad? Not bad? It's absolutely awful. Just like everything on this page, it makes major clarity sacrifices for absolutely no gain.

Answer (score 11):

I also think it's impossible, here's another failed but IMHO interesting attempt which avoids the `this`-access:

```
template<typename T>
struct class_t;

template<typename T, typename R>
struct class_t< R (T::*)() > { using type = T; };

struct Foo
{
   void self_f(); using self = typename class_t<decltype(&self_f)>::type;
};

#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert( std::is_same< Foo::self, Foo >::value, "" );
}
```

which fails because C++ requires you to qualify `self_f` with the class when you want to take it's address :(

Comment: And the same problem happens with a regular `int T::*` pointer to member variable. And `int self_var; typedef decltype(&self_var) self_ptr` doesn't work either, that's just a regular `int*`.

Answer (score 9):

I recently discovered that `*this` is allowed in a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. Described in § 5.1.1 (*from the [n3337 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)*):

> 3 *[..]* Unlike the object expression in other contexts, `*this` is
>   not required to be of complete type for purposes of class member
>   access (5.2.5) outside the member function body. *[..]*
>
> 4 Otherwise, if a *member-declarator* declares a non-static data
>   member (9.2) of a class X, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type
>   “pointer to X” within the optional *brace-or-equal-initializer*. It
>   shall not appear elsewhere in the *member-declarator*.
>
> 5 The expression `this` shall not appear in any other context. [
>   *Example:*
>
> ```
> class Outer {
>     int a[sizeof(*this)];               // error: not inside a member function
>     unsigned int sz = sizeof(*this);    // OK: in brace-or-equal-initializer
>
>     void f() {
>         int b[sizeof(*this)];           // OK
>         struct Inner {
>             int c[sizeof(*this)];       // error: not inside a member function of Inner
>         };
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

With that in mind, the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo* test = this;
    using self = decltype(test);

    static void smf()
    {
        self foo;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    static_assert( std::is_same< Foo::self, Foo* >::value, "" );
}
```

passes [Daniel Frey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21144038/3920237) `static_assert`.

<kbd>[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c96742b4cdf39c)</kbd>

Comment: You have an annoying useless variable `test` though

Comment: @Matt True, but I still found it interesting.

Comment: This could have worked without `= this`, right? And why not just `using self = Foo*;`

Comment: We didn't gain anything here surely, because we had to declare `test` to be of type, um, `Foo *`!

Answer (score 7):

Finally, a proper solution was found! The idea is by [@MitalAshok on github](https://github.com/MitalAshok/self_macro/).

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace SelfType
{
    template <typename T>
    struct Reader
    {
        friend auto adl_GetSelfType(Reader<T>);
    };

    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct Writer
    {
        friend auto adl_GetSelfType(Reader<T>){return U{};}
    };

    inline void adl_GetSelfType() {}

    template <typename T>
    using Read = std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(adl_GetSelfType(Reader<T>{}))>;
}

#define DEFINE_SELF \
    struct _self_type_tag {}; \
    constexpr auto _self_type_helper() -> decltype(::SelfType::Writer<_self_type_tag, decltype(this)>{}, void()) {} \
    using Self = ::SelfType::Read<_self_type_tag>;
```

Then:

```
struct A
{
    DEFINE_SELF
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Self, A>);
};
```

This uses stateful template metaprogramming to store the type in a context where it's accessible (in the trailing return type of a helper function) and then read the type where it would otherwise be unaccessible (at class scope).

The key here is how the writer is instantiated. Simply doing `auto _self_type_helper() -> Writer<...> {return {};}` doesn't work: the writer is instantiated with a delay, making the state accessible inside of any member function bodies, but not a the class scope.

But if you do `-> decltype(Writer<...>{}, void())`, or otherwise make the writer be a part of an expression affecting the type, then it starts working. I'm not entirely sure why that happens.

Comment: Great! Actually one can omit both `, void()` and the member function body, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rrb1jdTrK

Answer (score 4):

Unless the type needs to be member type of the enclosing class you could replace the use of `self` with `decltype(*this)`. If you use it in many places in your code you can define a macro `SELF` as follows:

```
#define SELF decltype(*this)
```

Comment: And you cannot use that outside of the class, or in nested classes

Comment: @Drax: It isn't supposed to be available outside the class.

Comment: @BenVoigt But it is suposed to be available in nested classes which is IMO the most interesting use case.

Comment: I don't think so. Shouldn't `self` refer to the immediately enclosing class and not the outer class?  But I don't know php that well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I guess that code and error is supposed to say "PHP doesn't have nested types"?

Comment: @BenVoigt: A cookie for you :)

Comment: If it isn't available outside the class, why not just write the class's name?

Answer (score 3):

Building upon the answer by hvd, I found that the only thing that was missing was removing the reference, that is why the std::is_same check fails (b/c the resulting type is actually a reference to the type). Now this parameter-less macro can do all the work. Working example below (I use GCC 8.1.1).

```
#define DEFINE_SELF \
    typedef auto _self_fn() -> std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type; \
    using self = decltype(((_self_fn*)0)())

class A {
    public:
    DEFINE_SELF;
};

int main()
{
    if (std::is_same_v<A::self, A>)
        std::cout << "is A";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't compile on other compilers than GCC.

Comment: It is accepted by MSVC as well: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Thx6hs469

Answer (score 1):

Provide my version. The best thing is that its use is the same as the native class. However, it doesn't work for template classes.

```
template<class T> class Self;

#define CLASS(Name) \
class Name##_; \
typedef Self<Name##_> Name; \
template<> class Self<Name##_>

CLASS(A)
{
    int i;
    Self* clone() const { return new Self(*this); }
};

CLASS(B) : public A
{
    float f;
    Self* clone() const { return new Self(*this); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I will repeat the obvious solution of "having to do it yourself". This is the succinct C++11 version of the code, which works with both simple classes and class templates:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_SELF(Type) \
    typedef Type TySelf; /**< @brief type of this class */ \
    /** checks the consistency of TySelf type (calling it has no effect) */ \
    void self_check() \
    { \
        static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(*((TySelf*)(0))), \
            decltype(*this)>::value, "TySelf is not what it should be"); \
    } \
    enum { static_self_check_token = __LINE__ }; \
    static_assert(int(static_self_check_token) == \
        int(TySelf::static_self_check_token), \
        "TySelf is not what it should be")
```

You can see it in action at [ideone](http://ideone.com/3N38yJ). The genesis, leading to this result is below:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_SELF(Type) typedef Type _TySelf; /**< @brief type of this class */

struct XYZ {
    DECLARE_SELF(XYZ)
};
```

This has the obvious problem with copy-pasting the code to a different class and forgetting to change XYZ, like here:

```cpp
struct ABC {
    DECLARE_SELF(XYZ) // !!
};
```

My first approach was not very original - making a function, like this:

```cpp
/**
 *  @brief namespace for checking the _TySelf type consistency
 */
namespace __self {

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (_TySelf must be declared the same as the type of class)
 *
 *  @tparam _TySelf is reported self type
 *  @tparam _TyDecltypeThis is type of <tt>*this</tt>
 */
template <class _TySelf, class _TyDecltypeThis>
class CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE;

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (specialization for assertion passing)
 *  @tparam _TySelf is reported self type (same as type of <tt>*this</tt>)
 */
template <class _TySelf>
class CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE<_TySelf, _TySelf> {};

/**
 *  @brief static assertion helper type
 *  @tparam n_size is size of object being used as assertion message
 *      (if it's a incomplete type, compiler will display object name in error output)
 */
template <const size_t n_size>
class CStaticAssert {};

/**
 *  @brief helper function for self-check, this is used to derive type of this
 *      in absence of <tt>decltype()</tt> in older versions of C++
 *
 *  @tparam _TyA is reported self type
 *  @tparam _TyB is type of <tt>*this</tt>
 */
template <class _TyA, class _TyB>
inline void __self_check_helper(_TyB *UNUSED(p_this))
{
    typedef CStaticAssert<sizeof(CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE<_TyA, _TyB>)> _TyAssert;
    // make sure that the type reported as self and type of *this is the same
}

/**
 *  @def __SELF_CHECK
 *  @brief declares the body of __self_check() function
 */
#define __SELF_CHECK \
    /** checks the consistency of _TySelf type (calling it has no effect) */ \
    inline void __self_check() \
    { \
        __self::__self_check_helper<_TySelf>(this); \
    }

/**
 *  @def DECLARE_SELF
 *  @brief declares _TySelf type and adds code to make sure that it is indeed a correct one
 *  @param[in] Type is type of the enclosing class
 */
#define DECLARE_SELF(Type) \
    typedef Type _TySelf; /**< @brief type of this class */ \
    __SELF_CHECK

} // ~self
```

It is kind of lengthy, but please bear with me here. This has the advantage of working in C++03 without `decltype`, as the `__self_check_helper` function is employed to deduce type of `this`. Also, there is no `static_assert`, but the `sizeof()` trick is employed instead. You could make it much shorter for C++0x. Now this will not work for templates. Also, there is a minor issue with the macro not expecting semicolon at the end, if compiling with pedantic, it will complain about an extra unnecessary semicolon (or you will be left with an odd looking macro not ending in semicolon in the body of `XYZ` and `ABC`).

Making a check on the `Type` that is passed to `DECLARE_SELF` is not an option, as that would only check the `XYZ` class (which is ok), oblivious to `ABC` (which has error). And then it hit me. A no-additional storage zero-cost solution that works with templates:

```cpp
namespace __self {

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (_TySelf must be declared the same as the type of class)
 *  @tparam b_check is the asserted value
 */
template <bool b_check>
class CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE2;

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (specialization for assertion passing)
 */
template <>
class CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE2<true> {};

/**
 *  @def DECLARE_SELF
 *  @brief declares _TySelf type and adds code to make sure that it is indeed a correct one
 *  @param[in] Type is type of the enclosing class
 */
#define DECLARE_SELF(Type) \
    typedef Type _TySelf; /**< @brief type of this class */ \
    __SELF_CHECK \
    enum { __static_self_check_token = __LINE__ }; \
    typedef __self::CStaticAssert<sizeof(CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE2<int(__static_self_check_token) == int(_TySelf::__static_self_check_token)>)> __static_self_check

} // ~__self
```

This simply makes static assertion on a unique enum value (or at least unique in case you don't write all of your code on a single line), no type-comparing trickery is employed, and it works as static assert, even in templates. And as a bonus - the final semicolon is now required :).

I'd like to thank Yakk for giving me a good inspiration. I wouldn't write this without first seeing his answer.

Tested with VS 2008 and g++ 4.6.3. Indeed, with the `XYZ` and `ABC` example, it complains:

```cpp
ipolok@ivs:~$ g++ self.cpp -c -o self.o
self.cpp:91:5: error: invalid application of âsizeofâ to incomplete type â__self::CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE2<false>â
self.cpp:91:5: error: template argument 1 is invalid
self.cpp: In function âvoid __self::__self_check_helper(_TyB*) [with _TyA = XYZ, _TyB = ABC]â:
self.cpp:91:5:   instantiated from here
self.cpp:58:87: error: invalid application of âsizeofâ to incomplete type â__self::CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE<XYZ, ABC>â
```

Now if we make ABC a template:

```cpp
template <class X>
struct ABC {
    DECLARE_SELF(XYZ); // line 92
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ABC<int> abc;
    return 0;
}
```

We will get:

```cpp
ipolok@ivs:~$ g++ self.cpp -c -o self.o
self.cpp: In instantiation of âABC<int>â:
self.cpp:97:18:   instantiated from here
self.cpp:92:9: error: invalid application of âsizeofâ to incomplete type â__self::CSELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE2<false>â
```

Only the line-number check triggered, as the function check was not compiled (as expected).

With C++0x (and without the evil underscores), you would need just:

```cpp
namespace self_util {

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (tokens in class and TySelf must match)
 *  @tparam b_check is the asserted value
 */
template <bool b_check>
class SELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE;

/**
 *  @brief compile-time assertion (specialization for assertion passing)
 */
template <>
class SELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE<true> {};

/**
 *  @brief static assertion helper type
 *  @tparam n_size is size of object being used as assertion message
 *      (if it's a incomplete type, compiler will display object name in error output)
 */
template <const size_t n_size>
class CStaticAssert {};

#define SELF_CHECK \
    /** checks the consistency of TySelf type (calling it has no effect) */ \
    void self_check() \
    { \
        static_assert(std::is_same<TySelf, decltype(*this)>::value, "TySelf is not what it should be"); \
    }

#define DECLARE_SELF(Type) \
    typedef Type TySelf; /**< @brief type of this class */ \
    SELF_CHECK \
    enum { static_self_check_token = __LINE__ }; \
    typedef self_util::CStaticAssert<sizeof(SELF_TYPE_MUST_BE_THE_SAME_AS_CLASS_TYPE<int(static_self_check_token) == int(TySelf::static_self_check_token)>)> static_self_check

} // ~self_util
```

I believe that the CStaticAssert bit is regrettably still required as it produces a type, which is typedef-ed in the template body (i suppose the same cannot be done with `static_assert`). The advantage of this approach is still its zero cost.

Comment: You’re essentially re-implementing `static_assert` here, aren’t you? Furthermore, your complete code is invalid because you’re using illegal (reserved) identifiers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, that is indeed the case. I don't have C++0x at the time, so I reimplemented static_assert in order to provide complete answer. I say that in the answer. Is it invalid? Can you point out how? It compiled fine, I'm using it right now.

Comment: The identifiers are invalid because C++ reserves everything with a leading underscore followed by uppercase letter, as well as two leading underscores in global scope, for the compiler. User code must not use it, but not all compilers will flag it as an error.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see, I did not know that. I have a lot of code that use that, never had problems with it on neither Linux / Mac / Windows. But I guess it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all about these wacky templates, how about something super-simple:

```
#define DECLARE_TYPEOF_THIS typedef CLASSNAME typeof_this
#define ANNOTATED_CLASSNAME(DUMMY) CLASSNAME

#define CLASSNAME X
class ANNOTATED_CLASSNAME (X)
{
public:
    DECLARE_TYPEOF_THIS;
    CLASSNAME () { moi = this; }
    ~CLASSNAME () { }
    typeof_this *moi;
    // ...
};    
#undef CLASSNAME

#define CLASSNAME Y
class ANNOTATED_CLASSNAME (Y)
{
    // ...
};
#undef CLASSNAME
```

Job done, unless you can't stand a couple of macros.  You can even use `CLASSNAME` to declare your constructor(s) (and, of course, destructor).

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/o5dlvE4Db5FbyZYq).

Comment: It has quite a pronounced effect on how the class can/must then be used

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How so?  I don't see it. I did, on reflection, remove the final sentence of my original post.  What I had there originally might have led you to think this.