# How to get this class type?

Tags: c++, macros

For example, I use macro to write a constructor method

```
#define DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR    T() { ...; }

class A
{
    DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR;
};
```

However, I don't know the concrete type T. I try decltype(*this). It cannot be used in constructor. Any way to do it? Please don't use macro arguments.

Comment: You have to name the type for the constructor. What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: Similar, but constructors need the exact name anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143835/can-i-implement-an-autonomous-self-member-type-in-c

Comment: I write some macros to implement constructors, assignments, clone and  put them together in a macro "DEFAULTS_ALL(members...)" or "DEFAULTS_ALL(T, members...)". Just want to use the 1st version.

Comment: You just have to pass the name of the class to that macro.

Comment: @user1899020, Why not just an editor snippet that makes all of those while creating the class?

Comment: @chris Macros with arguments seem easy to change. And I use BOOST_PP_FOR_EACH a lot where snippet doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should give argument to the macro.

like this:

```
#define DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(CLS_NAME) CLS_NAME() { ...; }
```

now in your class: (do you want it to be a private ctor?)

```
class A
{
    DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR(A);
};
```