# Refer to class in C++ macro

Tags: c++, class, macros, self-reference

I want to write

```
struct Foo{
    MY_MACRO
};
```

and have that expand into

```
struct Foo{
    void bar(Foo&){}
};
```

How do I define MY_MACRO?

The only things I can come up with is the following:

```
#define MY_MARCO(X) void bar(X&){}
struct Foo{
    MY_MACRO(Foo)
};
```

This comes very close but is sub ideal, as I do not want to repeat the class name.

Unfortunately the following does not compile:

```
struct Foo{
    void bar(decltype(*this)&){}
};
```

Comment: What about a template instead of a macro?

Comment: Generally, just **don't**. I did experiment once with a "NON_COPYABLE" macro, and tried out two different solutions, (1) passing the class name as macro argument, and (2) relying on an enclosing macro definition of "THIS_CLASS". But when the compilers caught up to speed, in particular Visual C++, the much better solution was to inherit from a non-copyable class.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) instead. Macros are evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closely related [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143835/can-i-implement-an-autonomous-self-member-type-in-c). The answer is that you can not (yet) write something that uses the type of the class definition you are in. You will have to write a macro that includes the start of the class definition (i.e the `struct Foo)` and some mechanism to facilitate the typedef.

Answer (score 1):

But you can use `decltype(*this)` in a static_assert. I.e.:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
    template <typename T>
    void bar(T& t) {
        static_assert(std::is_same<T&, decltype(*this)>::value,
                    "bar() only accepts objects of same type");
    }
};
```

Comment: Using a template is the only sane approach for this. I'd also suggest some research of mixins and CRTP to @B.S.. Using the C++ type system is far superior to using an ancient text replacement tool, which is what the preprocessor is.