# How to avoid repetition of the enclosing class type when auto and decltype() cannot be used

Tags: c++, generic-programming

I recently discovered the `auto` and `decltype()` features of C++11, which are excellent, as they allow eliminating a lot of redundant type code. However, there are contexts where they cannot be used. One example I'm primarily asking about is if you want to declare a variable whose type uses the enclosing class type, either directly, or as a template argument, and you don't have an initialization expression (which would have allowed you to use `auto`). This is particularly undesirable if the enclosing class type is a template class with many template parameters. For example:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5 > struct S {
    std::map<int,S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>*> m1;
    std::map<int,S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>*> m2;
    std::map<int,S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>*> m3;
    std::map<int,S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>*> m4;
    std::map<int,S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5>*> m5;
};
```

A logical solution is to use a typedef:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5 > struct S {
    typedef S<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5> ThisClass;
    std::map<int,ThisClass*> m1;
    std::map<int,ThisClass*> m2;
    std::map<int,ThisClass*> m3;
    std::map<int,ThisClass*> m4;
    std::map<int,ThisClass*> m5;
};
```

But it's still undesirable to have to declare a typedef that just repeats the enclosing class's type.

This can actually be solved if you're inside an instance method, by deducing the type of `*this`, although the necessary code is more verbose than I would like:

```
auto copy(void) {
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*this)>::type s = *this;
    // ... do stuff with s ...
    return s;
}
```

This solution does not work in class scope, because `this` is not allowed and is not meaningful outside of instance methods (the compiler complains `"invalid use of ‘this’ at top level"`).

So, my question is, when you can't use `auto` or `decltype()`, what is the recommended solution for avoiding repetition of the enclosing class's type when you have to use it inside the class definition? Is a typedef the only option?

Comment: I'm tempted to say that this is effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/21143835/560648. What do we think? In particular the solutions there may not work seeing as your `S` here is a class template.

Comment: They're related questions, but I would say my question is more general, since I was asking about how to avoid repetition of the class type, theoretically by any means (e.g. type deduction), and not specifically about getting a `self` alias, although that could be a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to repeat the template parameters if you are referring to the current instantiation.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5 > struct S {
    std::map<int,S*> m1;
    std::map<int,S*> m2;
    std::map<int,S*> m3;
    std::map<int,S*> m4;
    std::map<int,S*> m5;
};
```

The *injected-class-name* `S` refers to the current instantiation, in this case `S<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5>`.

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know that! That certainly helps. But the class name must still be repeated. Is there any way to avoid repeating the class name throughout the class definition?

Comment: @bgoldst I don't understand your question. You have to use *something* to refer to the class type - what could be clearer than the actual type?

Comment: I suspect the OP wants something like "self" in case the class name changes later. No, I'm pretty sure that kind of thing doesn't exist in C++. Maybe it'll be added when C++ gets reflection...

Comment: @Brian, correct, that's exactly what I was looking for. I guess I'll have to repeat the class name, which is not so bad now that I know the template parameters do not have to be repeated. Thanks!