# equivalence to decltype(*this) from a static method?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some macros that need access to the type of the current class and I currently get away with this via a DRY-violating pattern:

```
struct ThisScruct{
    int a;
    double b;
    //example static method using this - purely example - not full usecase

    static size_t sum_offsets(){
       typedef ThisStruct SelfT;
       return offsetof(SelfT, a) + offsetof(SelfT, b);
    }
};
```

This comes up a lot with use of the [`offsetof`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/) keyword, at least in my own work.

Now before you lock onto `this` not being accessible via a static method - realize I just want to know how to get the type `ThisStruct` in a generic/macro friendly way from a static method context.  I don't actually need/want an instance and am looking for way that actually works like the above without typedeffing `SelfT`.

Edit: Something similar is asked in [Can I implement an autonomous `self` member type in C++?](/q/21143835) - but I am worried about a diamond problem forming with classes both inheriting from the accepted answer's `Self` class.

Comment: What does `declare_static_methods_using_offsetof` mean? The `typedef` you have is probably the best way of doing this.

Comment: @TonyD when these macros are invoked - I do not have access to "this" because the context is static methods.

Comment: @Praetorian I've been using typedef for a long time to do this; I refuse to believe it is the best way to do it :-)!  I filled in something concrete for declare_static_methods_using_offsetof

Comment: I knew I'd seen this question before, finally managed to find it - https://stackoverflow.com/q/21143835/241631 Would you consider that a duplicate?

Comment: @Praetorian at face value I would; however the answer there will break with inheritance involved (two classes inheriting Self now being involved in a parent child relationship) if I'm reading it right.  I'll edit my example again.  Btw great memory - I searched for a prior question more than a few times.

Comment: Sum of offsets doesn't make sense since it is cumulative.  If you had a third variable, what would you get?  If this is a base class and if you just took the address of the last variable and added the sizeof it, that would give you the offset of whatever follows.

Comment: @JasonNewton Just noticed your "example static method" - do you realise that if you put the `typedef` just once in the `struct` definition, it can be used by any number of static member functions...? [see here](http://ideone.com/vjdK4B) And re your comment to me above - yeah - ADD_THIS was a stupid idea.

Comment: @cup - don't nit pick the example usecase

Comment: There's no straightforward way to do this, but if you're really using it for structs, have you considered having a constexpr default constructor for the type and just making the method non-static? Calling ThisStruct{}.sum_offsets() isn't much worse than ThisStruct::sum_offsets(), and should optimize to the same thing with any reasonable compiler.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the CRT-pattern to access the typename generically, you just need to specify it in the inheritance list.

```
    template<class T>
struct Type { using type = T; };

struct ThisScruct : Type<ThisStruct> {
    int a;
    double b;

    // this function can be copy-pasted into every
    // struct definition, which is inherited from
    // Type and contains the members a and b
    static size_t sum_offsets(){
       typedef Type::type SelfT;
       return offsetof(SelfT, a) + offsetof(SelfT, b);
    }
};
```

You might rename Type to a more descriptive name. But you might consider replacing this functionality completely by the CRT-pattern, by moving the functions into the inherited struct.

```
    template<class T>
struct SumOffsets {
    static size_t sum_offsets(){
       typedef T SelfT;
       return offsetof(SelfT, a) + offsetof(SelfT, b);
    }
};

struct ThisStruct : SumOffsets<ThisStruct> {
    int a;
    double b;
};
```

The function `sum_offsets` can be accessed by `ThisStruct::sum_offsets`, because even static functions are inherited. There is no additional overhead, because neither virtual functions are involved nor `SumOffsets` has data members.