# Explicitly access static member variable in static member method - in C++

Tags: c++, class, static, this, static-members

I know how to access static member variable in static member method - these are two ways I usually use (very simplified):

```
class S{
    private:
        static const int testValue = 5;
    public:
        static int getTestValue0(){
            return testValue;
        }
        static int getTestValue1(){
            return S::testValue;
        }
};
```

( working example on : http://ideone.com/VHCSbh )

**My question is:** is there any more explicit way how to access static member variable than `ClassName::staticMemberVar`?

Is there something like `self::` in C++ ?

...simply I am looking for something like `this` for referencing static members.

Comment: _"Is there something like `self::` in C++ ?"_ Nope. You can provide a class local typedef for `self` though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143835/can-i-implement-an-autonomous-self-member-type-in-c

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ well I guess I'm stuck with class name then... thanks :)

Comment: @jave.web As mentioned you can provide a local `typedef MyClass self;`. I'm doing so for lengthy class names with big template parameter lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is there something like `self::` in C++ ?*

No there is no such feature, but you can use a class local `typedef`:

```
class MyClass {
    typedef MyClass self;
    static int testValue;
    static int getTestValue1(){
        return self::testValue;
    }
};
```

See a working [demo](http://ideone.com/ch7tzR).

Comment: So will this be really only LOCAL typedef? (Can I use it in more static classes in one application?)

Comment: @jave.web  Yes, it's even `private`

Comment: Yes I know it's private because there is no "secret-level" definition :) I just wanted to be sure that one class's `self::` won't even try to access another's. :)

Comment: Since C++11, one could also use `using self = MyClass;`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support to use something other than class name. You'll need to implement it.

> Static Function Members: By declaring a function member as static, you
>   make it independent of any particular object of the class. A static
>   member function can be called even if no objects of the class exist
>   and the static functions are accessed using only the class name and
>   the scope resolution operator ::.

to read details [click here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_static_members.htm)

Comment: _"There  is no support to use something other than class name."_ Proven wrong.