# Automatically declare member pointers to their own classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, type-inference, compile-time

My question is:
**Is there a way to declare static member pointers to their own classes automatically?**

I have a C++ state machine, in which classes have static pointers to their own classes. This means I can bind a given object to the pointer in its class uniquely. In other words, from each class, only 1 instance can be bound to the static pointers, which pointers then can be used to select from the pool of instances the one that is currently bound.

```
class A {
public:
   static A *ptr;
   void bind() { ptr = this; }
}

class B {
public:
   static B *ptr;
   void bind() { ptr = this; }
}
```

To me this seems like there has to be some way to abstract this. The process in each class is basically the same: a static pointer to the class and a bind function to assign `this` to said pointer. (I'm aware of the dangers regarding the lifetimes of each particular bound object, consider this taken care of.)

As far as I know, these type of abstractions are usually performed with inheritance, however I can't seem to find a way to abstract out the type of `ptr` in a hierarchy, or using template classes.

The optimal solution would be one that doesn't need any information from the programmer regarding the type of `ptr` in any of the classes, since it seems to be available information at compile time.

Can this be done? Can it be avoided to explicitly declare `ptr` in each class and automate the process?

This is the closes I got to a solution, but did not succeed: [C++ - Are there ways to get current class type with invariant syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33230665/c-are-there-ways-to-get-current-class-type-with-invariant-syntax)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That seems to be big nonsense, and should not be done at all. `static` shares that for All instances.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Let me elaborate a little. What I'm planning is that for example class `A` will have numerous objects (let them be `a`, `b` and `c`) from which I want to use only 1 at a time. If `a` calls its `bind` function, then I can simply derefer `A::ptr` to get `a` (given it is still in scope). The situation is the same with class `B` and some others as well. This seems to be abstractable to me, in which I have been unsuccessful. Is this such a bad idea?

Comment: I am struggling to understand what you are trying to do. This inhibits my ability to render meaningful aid.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm working on an OpenGL-based graphical library. To draw an object for example, I have to choose a shader from a pool of `Shader` objects, a texture from a pool of `Texture` objects etc. I can bind the `Shader` and `Texture` object I want to use and then the object can just derefer `Shader::ptr` and `Texture::ptr` to get the bound shader and the bound texture. What I'm trying to do is to abstract away having to declare `ptr` explicitly in `Shader` and in `Texture`. Is it clearer?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. It's error-prone. IMO better to just make local pointers/references when you need them. If your items come from a container with an index then keep track of that if you wish, at least when it all goes horribly wrong the incorrect index will be easier to track down than a pointer.

Comment: @DanielVarga that's a horribly bad idea, yes. The closest thing I can think of is some class type reference, like available in Delphi, Smalltalk, Ada or such, but not with c++. c++ meta programming is restricted to compile time template expressions. There are no reflection utilities available with standard c++.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm not trying to be stubborn here, but I just don't get how this is a _horrible_ idea. The answer by Sam Varshavchik works exactly like I want it to, in compile time, what's wrong with that? I get that it might be error-prone according to Retired Ninja, but not how this is _horrible_. That said, I'm not adamant on this approach, in fact, I've been considering simply storing these objects in an STL container myself, I just wanted to explore this approach as well. My main reason for this approach is it being a nice reflection on OpenGL itself being a state machine.

Comment: @DanielVarga it works as long you have everything available at compile time with c++. That's a narrow field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of would be a [CRTP-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp), something like:

```
template<typename T> struct current_instance {

    static T *ptr;

    void bind() { ptr = static_cast<T *>(this); }
};

// ...

template<typename T> T *current_instance<T>::ptr;

//--------------------------------------------------------------

class A : current_instance<A> {
  // ...
};

class B : current_instance<B> {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Sam Varshavchik for the quick answer! This seems to work just like I'd like it to. I have a theoretical question though if I may: in an `A` object (call it `a`), in the `bind` function, `this` refers to the`current_instance` object, currently a subset of `a` which is then cast to refer to `a` itself. How exactly is this possible? Is it guaranteed that the memory addresses are the same? It would not be possible if there were multiple base classes. Or is `static_cast` so smart that it can perform `base* -> derived*` conversions? What conditions are required for this to be possible?

Comment: `static_cast` is just that smart, casting base to derived, as long as there's no multiple or virtual inheritance.