# Typedef to surrounding type in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang++

Is there a way to build a `typedef` inside a type declaration to the declared (surrounding) type itself without stating the type's name?

Example:

```
class X
{
  public:
    typedef <fill in magic here> MyType;
  //...
};
```

Background:
This seems silly on the first look. I need this because I build compile-time-reflection of my data classes using macros.
So there is a macro inserted into the declaration of the data class which needs to deal with the type it is inserted into.
So far I found working solutions for MSVC and g++ which both rely on what I think are flaws in the implementation. So they may not work on a newer version.
Clang does not "eat" either of these solutions.

My current solution for MSVC defines a method and then takes it's address only by it's name and calls a small helper that "returns" the type of it's class. (Clang and g++ expect the full name of the method including it's class name).

My current solution for g++ defines a static method with return type `std::remove_reference(decltype(*this))`. (Clang and MSVC do not allow `this` in the static context).

I would absolutely prefer a standard conform solution but a special solution for clang would also be ok for the moment.

If nothing works I have to pass the class' name to the macro but I try to avoid this since I already have plenty of code using the macro.

**EDIT**: Adding a sample on how the reflection works (which may clarify what I need):

```
class X : public Y
{
  public:
    //.. constructor and such stuff...

    int a;
    double b;
    std::string c;

    CLASSHEAD(Y)
      FIELD(a)
      FIELD(b)
      FIELD(c)
    CLASSFOOT
};
```

`CLASSHEAD` is the macro that should define `typedef`. It is a VAR_ARGS macro where the arguments receive the base classes. As said: It is possible to give it the class' name as it's first argument (resulting in `CLASSHEAD(X, Y)` in the example). But I nearly cannot imagine that there is no solution to such a "simply" task as typedef'ing the surrounding type...

Comment: Actually, it is not clear to my why you can't just do `typedef X MyType;`, and then have the macros use `MyType`?

Comment: So will all of the classes expected to use this mechanism inherit from the same base? (In which case I can reinstate my CRTP answer).

Comment: The only reason I can think for needing this is in function signatures. Within the function itself, you would use `typedef std::remove_reference(decltype(*this))::type MyType;` as above. You could make those functions templates, then `static_assert(std::is_same<T, MyType>::value);`. Not pretty, can't think of anything better.

Comment: I am afraid to get standard compliant solution you must wait until new standard is ready with type reflection (in your case introspection). See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3814.html

Comment: Seems like the way to do this is to define a macro that creates the class declaration. The class name would be a parameter to the macro, and it will then emit the `public CLASSNAME MyType;` line.

Comment: I work around this by putting in any class that needs this feature `typedef X self; typedef Y inherited;`  at the top.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143835/can-i-implement-an-autonomous-self-member-type-in-c)

Comment: Just a remark: g++-5.2 does not accept the decltype "solution" in a static context.

Comment: Please do not deface your questions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Nohting works so using the class Name in the macro is the only working solution

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly meet your specification, but I think its pretty close:

```
class X
{
//Stuff...

//Use Macros to add:
struct MyType;

//Use class closing macro to insert variable between class-ending brace and semicolon      


} TYPE_VAR;
//Perhaps add random stuff to TYPE_VAR name to avoid collisions, like __FILE__
struct decltype(TYPE_VAR)::MyType
{
    typedef decltype(TYPE_VAR) V;
};
```

Then access X's type using

```
X::MyType::V
```

For example, a simplified CLASSFOOT might look like this:

```
#define CLASSFOOT /*Your classfoot here*/ } TYPE_VAR; struct decltype(TYPE_VAR)::MyType {typedef decltype(TYPE_VAR) V;
//No }; at end on purpose- this will come from the class in which you placed CLASSFOOT
```

Is this good enough for your purposes?

Comment: A down-side is that `MyType::V` could not be used inside the definition of `X` (a feature which I think OP needs)

Comment: This does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using macros, you could use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/21143997/2173029

```
#define CLASS_WITH_MY_TYPE(ClassName) \ 
    class ClassName                   \
    {                                 \
       using MyType = ClassName;
```

And then use like

```
CLASS_WITH_MY_TYPE(X)
public:
  struct Y
  {
    using T = MyType;
  };
};

static_assert(std::is_same<X, typename X::Y::T>::value, "");
```

Marked as community wiki since @Chris mentioned the link and the original answer was posted by @Bartek Banachewicz

Comment: @RüdigerStevens I thought you meant the `CLASSHEAD` macro.