# How come there's no 'this_class' - the static equivalent of 'this'?

Tags: c++, reflection, static, this

When you're in a C++ non-static method, you can use the `this` variable to refer to the current instance; and through the instance you also have the type. In static methods, I would expect to have something like a `this_class` type available to me, which is the type of the class in which I'm implementing the method. Even if it's not inherited (i.e. for `class B : public A`, method `A::foo()` will have `this_class` being `A` even when accessed through `B`) - it would still be useful, for example when you're implementing a static method in a class with many template arguments, and you want to call some out-of-class function templated on your class's type.

Illustration of use:

```
template <typename T> void foo() { std::cout << typeid(T).name(); }

template <typename S, typename T, typename U, typename AndLots, typename More>
class A {
    /* ... */
    static void say_my_name( foo<this_class>(); }
}
```

So, was this possibility ever considered? Are there reasons it would complicate things for the developer or the compiler?

Comment: this is where Objective-C beats C++

Comment: Shouldn't [`decltype(*this)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) give you this info?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's impossible in a static method... :-)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143835/can-i-implement-an-autonomous-self-member-type-in-c).

Comment: @einpoklum Then it's unclear what you're asking about. Could you illustrate with some (pseudo code) example, what exactly you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: @LogicStuff: a `Self<T>` mixin is not so bad, I guess... except that the hassle in having your classes inherit it is on the same order of magnitude of the benefit of not having to inherit it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It seems other people get it... but - edited to clarify more.

Comment: @einpoklum And `foo<A>();` doesn't do the trick for you?

Comment: @einpoklum [See here please](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7675eaffa1e4d35b).

Answer (score 1):

> How come there's no 'this_class' - the static equivalent of 'this'?

You don't need it, because it's trivial.

You can either write

```
template <typename S, typename T, typename U, typename AndLots, typename More>
class A {
    public:
    /* ... */
    static void say_my_name() { foo<A>(); }
                                // ^^^
};
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7675eaffa1e4d35b)

or

```
template <typename S, typename T, typename U, typename AndLots, typename More>
class A {
    public:
    /* ... */
    typedef A<S,T,U,AndLots,More> this_type;

    static void say_my_name() { foo<this_type>(); }
};
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/471c3c1bbe728492)

if you prefer.

Comment: The "this type" is what I want to have without specifying it explicitly. So, your answer is that it's not useful enough to have in the language?

Comment: _"So, your answer is that it's not useful enough to have in the language?"_ Yes, that's what I meant. For most cases you should get away with my 1st sample.

Comment: @einpoklum See also [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1187732870f863ef) or [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a9b07fc26bd5d91).