# this in unevaluated context in static member functions

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, static-members, static-functions

Why `this` is not allowed in unevaluated context in static member functions?

```
struct A
{
    void f() {}
    static void callback(void * self) // passed to C function
    {
        static_cast< decltype(this) >(self)->f();
    }
};
```

This code gives an error:

> error: 'this' is unavailable for static member functions
>
> ```
> static_cast< decltype(this) >(self)->f();
>                       ^~~~
> ```

`decltype(this)` there is needed for brevity (sometimes it is much more shorter, then `VeryVeryLongClassName *`), another advantage is the fact that intention is more clear.

What Standard says about using `this` in unevaluated contexts in static member functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ type of enclosing class in static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143275/c-type-of-enclosing-class-in-static-member-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see how it matters that `this` appears within an unevaluated context, you've referred to something that [doesn't exist](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.static.mfct#2) in a static member function, so how is the compiler supposed to deduce the type of `this` within this context?

As a corollary, the [type of `this`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.this#1) in a non-static member function is dependent on the cv-qualifier of said member function, `decltype(this)` would yield `T const*` if the member function were `const`, and `T *` if it weren't. Thus, the type is dependent on the context of the expression. In your example, the context has no `this` pointer.

To alleviate the pain of having to name the class you could add an alias for it.

```
class VeryVeryLongClassName
{
    using self = VeryVeryLongClassName;
};
```

Comment: The `this` pointer doesn't have a value in a static member function, but it does have a type and value category.  So says your second link... (probably modified since you wrote this answer)

Answer (score 2):

The current draft of the Standard has [some conflicting information](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#3).

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class `X`, the expression `this` is a *prvalue* of type "pointer to *cv-qualifier-seq* `X`" wherever `X` is the current class between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*.
> **It shall not appear within the declaration of either a static member function or an explicit object member function of the current class (although its type and value category are defined within such member functions as they are within an implicit object member function).**

First it prohibits the expression `this` in a static member function, but then it says that the type and value category of `this` are defined within static member functions (and it does so in a way which resolves the question of *cv* qualification).  Which seems useless if there is no way to refer to said `this` to obtain its type.

A potential resolution would be for the rule to change from "shall not appear" to "shall not be evaluated", which would immediately permit it to appear in unevaluated context such as `decltype` and `sizeof`.